# the same LOG elements that are repeated when I haven't even declared them in the application

Tags: java, android

Just need help, in my Logcat console window under android studio (Flamingo), I only see the same LOG elements that are repeated when I haven't even declared them in the application

I don't have a solution yet, can someone help me?

My logcat out:

```
18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.616 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.674 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.676 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.724 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.726 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.768 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.798 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.825 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.827 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.856 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.857 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.883 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.885 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.908 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.910 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.925 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.928 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:46.990 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:46.995 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.039 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.041 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.059 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.061 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.114 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.116 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.149 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.152 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.177 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.178 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.198 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.201 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.243 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.244 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.293 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.298 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.351 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.353 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.427 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.428 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.450 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.452 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
2023-05-17 21:00:47.485 18148-18148 AndroidRuntime          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  Shutting down VM
2023-05-17 21:00:47.491 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 4 9
2023-05-17 21:00:47.493 18148-18478 eglCodecCommon          com.pilias.app.facebook.desk         D  setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

These are messages coming from other applications running on your device. You can filter the logs to only show the ones from your package.